Colimits in commutative Banach algebras?
Let $K$ be a complete non-Archimedean field. It is known that the category $\mathrm{Ban}_K$ of $K$-Banach spaces with bounded linear maps does not have infinite colimits. The usual argument for $\mathrm{Ban}_K$ not having infinite coproducts of non-zero objects requires rescaling an infinite family of bounded linear maps so that the norms ranging across the family is unbounded.
But does the category $\mathrm{CAlg}\,\mathrm{Ban}_K$ of commutative unital $K$-Banach algebras with bounded $K$-algebra maps have arbitrary colimits? The above argument fails for commutative unital algebras because one cannot rescale algebra maps preserving 1.

I’m not sure how being non-Archimedean affects this, but you can rescale the norms for particular elements. Consider the algebra $A = K1 \oplus Kx$ where $1$ is the unity and $x$ is s.t. $x^2 = 0$. Then for any $r \in K$, $r > 0$, $|a1 + bx|_r = |a| + r|y|$ is a norm that makes $A$ into a commutative unital $K$-Banach algebra, which we shall denoted by $A_r$. Then the formal identity map $A_1 \to A_r$ is a unital algebra homomorphism having norm $\max{1, r}$, which can be as large as desired.

(This tells you the coproduct of $\text{cf}(K)$ many copies of $A_1$ does not exist, at the very least.)

I don't see how this implies infinite coproducts of $A_1$ do not exist. I presume you want to consider $$T : \overset{\hat}{\bigotimes} A_1 \to \overset{\hat}{\bigotimes} A_r$$ and use $\vert T \vert$ to bound all $\max{1 , r}$, but I could not get this to work because I think it needs a uniform bound on the operator norms of the inclusions $$A_r \to \overset{\hat}{\bigotimes} A_r$$.

Yeah, you’re right, it was a mistake to rescale the norm on $A_1$. Should have just use a rescaling map $f_r: A_1 \to A_1$ defined by $f_r(a1+bx) = a1+rbx$.

I would go with (non-existing) filtered colimits since they should be the same as for Banach spaces.
